# variable from a link to a controller in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

```
foreach($data as $row) {
                $output .= '
                    <a href="{{ route('result', [ 'id' => $row->id ])}}" class="dropdown-item" type="button">'.$row->nome.'</a>
                    ';
            }
```

When a click on the link a want to go to another page called "result" passing $row->id to the view.

LiveSearch controller::

```
public function result($id)
{
    return view('result')->with('id', $id);
}
```

the route on web.php:

```
Route::get('/result/{id}', 'LiveSearch@result')->name('result');
```

but it doesn't work, giving me the 404 error.

Comment: remove `/` from `route('/result', [ 'id' => $row->id ])` and named your route as `result` , use `Route::get('/result/{id}', 'LiveSearch@result')->name('result');`

Comment: @RishiRaut `->name()`, not `->named()`

Comment: @RishiRaut I tried but it doesn't work also adding the name. I edited the question with your advice

Answer (score 0):

WHy are you using type button in anchor tag? Try this
    `<a href="{{ route('/result', [ 'id' => $row->id ])}}" class="btn btn-primary">'.$row->nome.'</a>`

Answer (score 0):

public function result(Request $request) {
..... Replace $id with $request->id ... when calling view

Comment: Is LiveSearch a controller? If so it should be called LiveSearchController and in route should be called the same.

Comment: yeah it is a controller but it would not solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `{{ url('result', [ 'id' => $row->id ])}}`

Instead of `{{ route('result', [ 'id' => $row->id ])}}`